# Fine tune of aesthetics for a plot in glmmADMB using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, glm

I'm learning ggplot2 right now. To do so, I'm reproducing some plots I see in R packages in order to learn ggplot2 commands. Now I'm trying to reproduce the plot in the page 4 of the vignette of package glmmADMB - http://glmmadmb.r-forge.r-project.org/glmmADMB.pdf . Please see the image below:

[image: glmmADMB]

However, I'm trying a lot of different codes, but I'm struggling with the aesthetics. So far, the best I could do was use the code

```
ggplot(data=Owls, aes(x=ArrivalTime, y=NegPerChick)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=SexParent)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(lty=SexParent), method="loess") + 
  geom_smooth(aes(lty=FoodTreatment), method="loess")
```

to get this plot:

[image: glmmADMB2]

Do you guys have an idea on how can I work it out to have the plot I want? I want to match the colors and the fitting lines from the original plot in mine.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to customize the theme: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/theme.html. That's generally how one customizes a plot. If there is a specific part that you cannot  figure out, then maybe ask a more specific question.

Comment: Use [the source](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/vignettes/glmmADMB.Rnw?view=markup&root=glmmadmb) Luke!